# How do I create a virtual machine on azure when there are no sizes available for my subscription/location

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

## Context

I am trying to create my first virtual machine in azure.

I have a pay as you go subscription, I have created a resource group

## Steps to create issue

- I click the button that says 'add a virtual machine'
- I fill in the details of the resource group, I add the region (west germany as I am currently in germany), and I press the button marked 'size'.
- A nice drop down list of all the sizes appears, and every single item on the list is greyed out.

## What I have tried

- I did a google search, but most questions seemed to be about 'specific sizes not available in their region'. At the moment I would be happy if there was even one size available
- I tried waiting 24 hours in case it was a glitch and tried again, and it was just the same.
- The first time I tried I was on the free subscription, but I have upgraded to pay as you go
- I asked microsoft on their chat and after an initial look, they said an expert would get to me in two or three working days.
- I tried creating new resource groups, and changing the region (lots of different regions tried)

## Error messages

There is no message as such: just all entries being greyed out, and a mouse over (i) that says `Size not available
This size is currently unavailable in this location for this subscription: NotAvailableForSubscription`

Comment: is it happening on the other locations too?

Comment: Thank you for responding Thiago. I tried lots of regions, and three different resource groups incase it was 'user error'. In all of them I get the same grayed out table, and the same message in the (i) NotAvailableForSubscription

Comment: I tried on a different browser and created a new account and had exactly the same experience. I didn't upgrade that account though: this new account was just a free trial.

Comment: Further data: the automated microsoft troubleshooter informs me that my quotas are exceeded, but I have zero virtual machines at the moment

Comment: this is not normal, try get in touch with the support

Comment: please take a look on this blog post: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

Answer (score 4):

Azure seems to be blocking new account signups from accessing resources of *any* tier, while you are in the "free trial" period.

Per [this blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/), the limitations are to prioritize various essential industries during the COVID health crisis.

I do wish they were doing so with more transparency.  If you fall within those categories, opening a support ticket will likely help. Otherwise, you likely need to look to a different cloud provider.

Comment: Microsoft being Microsoft...

Comment: That's crap. Microsoft is just a shifty company. No VM is available on our accounts except $400+ per month VMs. That makes no sense